# Zest, featuring an offline browser for Stack Overflow

Tags: app

### About

My app has similar goals to [Stackdump](https://stackapps.com/questions/3610/stackdump-an-offline-browser-for-stackexchange-sites). It is a browser which doesn't require internet connection and allows full-text search of Stack Overflow posts from the [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). As opposed to being a server-based web app, it is wrapped in a convenient standalone [Electron](http://electron.atom.io) app.

Its main feature is an API documentation browser, but the SO search is something I'm particularly excited about, so I thought it's worth sharing here.

### Screenshots

[image: Example search result]
[image: Tags choice]

### License

Zest (the application, not the content) is licensed under the MIT License. The content is obviously licensed under the cc-wiki license.

### Download

The app is available for OS X, Linux, and Windows, and the relevant download pages are linked from http://zestdocs.org/. Code is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/zestdocs/zest).

### Implementation details

As a performance and storage optimization, user is given a choice of Stack Overflow tags to index, which are then selectively extracted from the .7z archives and made searchable. The whole process seems to take roughly below 2 hours on modern machines.

The XML parser is written in C++ basing on [Xerces](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) and the search engine is also C++ - based on the [LucenePlusPlus](https://github.com/LucenePlusPLus) port of the Lucene engine.

The HTML GUI is written in ClojureScript (maybe not the best choice for me, but I always wanted to try writing something larger in a Lisp-like language).

### Limitations and plans

There is obviously lots of work to be done here, for now the SO answers displayed aren't even sorted properly by score, but I think it's worth gathering some initial feedback. (It also seems to help with keeping my motivation to work on it when I get some feedback.)

Anyway, some of other possible improvements I may implement in the future:

1. Either a new SO dump .torrent file, or downloading directly from Internet Archive via HTTP. The current .torrent file used by Zest contains data from 2014. See [the 2nd half of this GitHub comment](https://github.com/zestdocs/zest/issues/7#issuecomment-182932627) for more discussion
2. (Semi-)automated updates of the dump data.
3. Support for other Stack Exchange websites than Stack Overflow.

### Contact

Feel free to raise GitHub issues, email me at my address which is in the git repo, or join me in the mostly empty #zestdocs on Freenode.